# doing 'else' if looking for a specific(server/guild) for a send command

Tags: discord.py, bots

CODE:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

if message.content == 'milkshake':
  await message.channel.send("=gus")
else client.guilds.get('**said id**'):
  await message.channel.send("=bad")
```

How can I change it so it will say that in any other server it would say `=gus` but in a specific server it would say `=bad`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do:

```
if client.guilds.get('ID'):
    if message.content == 'milkshake':
        await message.channel.send('=bad')
else:
    if message.content == 'milkshake':
        await message.channel.send('=gus')
```

*If this helps in any way please consider upvoting and/or marking as answer :)*

Answer (score 0):

@DefaultsModel.exe's answer won't work I don't believe.
What you want

```
if (message.guild==client.guilds.get('ID')):
    if message.content == 'milkshake':
        await message.channel.send('=bad')
else:
    if message.content == 'milkshake':
        await message.channel.send('=gus')
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
if (message.guild.id==#put id here):
    if message.content == 'milkshake':
        await message.channel.send('=bad')
else:
    if message.content == 'milkshake':
        await message.channel.send('=gus')
```

Comment: Thanks, your alternative option worked well. Thank you '@Iron Man'